# Does using "yet" affects the context of the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

**e.g.**

> I have not eaten my lunch.
>
> I have not eaten my lunch yet.

How do the above 2 sentences differ?

Answer (score 3):

They differ only subtly. Perhaps the second suggests that the person still intends to eat their
lunch – probably sometime soon.

For an ordinary daily task (like eating lunch), the difference between the two is minuscule. But consider this example:

> I have not run a marathon.
>   I have not run a marathon yet.

Now the second sentence (possibly) suggests that the speaker perhaps intends to try to complete a marathon someday.

This doesn't mean that a runner who aspires to complete a marathon someday wouldn't say the first, or that everyone who says the second intends to run a marathon. But the word *yet* – whether it's included or omitted – does connote those things a little bit.